# how to load the private key from a .der file into java private key object

Tags: java, format, bouncycastle, pkcs#8

I'm writing a java program to import private keys from files within the file system and make a private key object, using java... 
I could do it for files in `.pem` format but, with .der format, I had no idea what to do, since I couldnt firstly detect the algorithm used to generate the keys.
within `.pem` files I could determine the algorithm from the header for `PKCS#1` which have a header like
        `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----`
formats and used the bouncycastle `pem` reader for those in PKCS#8 which have a header
`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`
but with those in .der format no idea :(
also if anyone have an idea about `.key` format tell me
thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your DER files are in PKCS#8 format, you can use the Java [KeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) and do something like this:

```
// Read file to a byte array.
String privateKeyFileName = "C:\\myPrivateKey.der";   
Path path = Paths.get(privateKeyFileName);
byte[] privKeyByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);

PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyByteArray);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

PrivateKey myPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

System.out.println("Algorithm: " + myPrivKey.getAlgorithm());
```

You mentioned that you may not know what algorithm the key is using.  I'm sure there is a more elegant solution than this, but you could create several `KeyFactory` objects (one for each possible algorithm) and try to `generatePrivate()` on each one until you do not get an `InvalidKeySpecException`.

Comment: thanks I know I could use this, but I want it for an application that works with all types of keys, I'm not interested in a certain key

Comment: @monim, that's why I mentioned that you can instantiate multiple KeyFactories...one for each type of key that is possible, and then just catch the exceptions for those it doesn't work for.  The one it does work for will give you the correct PrivateKey object.

Comment: hmmmm, and what if the DER file in PKCS#1 , this strategy wont work

Answer (score 1):

thanks @gtrig using ur idea and editing the code like this :

```
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(KeyBytes);  
            try 
                KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
                algorithm = keyFactory.getAlgorithm();
                //algorithm = "RSA";
                //publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException excep1) {
                try {
                    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
                    privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
                    algorithm = keyFactory.getAlgorithm();
                    //publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
                } catch (InvalidKeySpecException excep2) {

                    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
                    privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

                } // inner catch
            }
```

the code is working well now

Comment: This won't work if the key is in PKCS#1 format. In order to read both PKCS#1 and PKCS#8 PEM/DER files, I use the source code of Apache JMeter's [`org.apache.jmeter.protocol.oauth.sampler.PrivateKeyReader`](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1178/code/branches/jmeter/jmeter/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/oauth/sampler/PrivateKeyReader.java).

Comment: How do I use the source, @JulienKronegg? Could you please post an example in a separate answer?

Comment: @arik: PrivateKey pk = (new PrivateKeyReader("/path/to/myfile.der")).getPrivateKey();